# Facebook business manager to use Page API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For those that will read it, thank you very much (and special thanks for helpers).

We're having some trouble with Facebook, and we're not sure if it's related to Facebook latest scandals.
Facebook forums are not the most responsive, so I thought to give it a shot here.

The goal is to read posts from our customers pages.
We thought that to create Business Manager with system user, ask our customers to add us as partners to their pages, generates page tokens and use the {page_id}/feed API.

In order to test this flow, we did the next steps:

1. created BM
2. created Facebook Page (via the BM)
3. created an app
4. associated the app with the BM.
5. in BM settings page - created System User.
6. assigned the system user with the created page (admin role)
7. generated token (related to the app created).
8. using Graph API, called to me/accounts (with the access token given at 7).
9. I verified that the page id was in the response, and took the access_token from the response.
10. tried to call {page_id}/feed (or to /me).

This is the error I received:

```
{  
"error": {    
"message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 10,
"fbtrace_id": "BV/3aru6KTJ"  
    }
}
```

Thanks for anybody that helps.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS says you can only access pages you “own” without review; I think that means app user must be a page admin.

Comment: I'm struggling on the same problem since yersterday...But yeah first of all you need to be administrator of your  FB page.

Answer (score 1):

seems you have go far:
take a look from the image and put some details to be approved after that you have to submit it. approval will take time just be patient.

App Review-> Add Items-> Page Content Access.. hopefully the rest instruction from developer.facebook.com will be understandable.

for those newbies just take a look how to start an app.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Comment: Thanks @user1308314.
If I don't have a login page, since I'm using my app in my backend, how can send my app for review?
They require login screenshots